# Deploy custom tab style

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, tab

Please tell me how to deploy custom tab styles from one sandbox to another. Will this be a manual step. I did not see this component in metadata api guide nor is it listed as a manual step. Thanks in advance and sorry if I have overlooked something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metadata for custom tab has reference to the document and hence you will deploy tabs metadata and also the document that has image .Observe the icon attribute in below metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <icon>Sample/AccountsTab.gif</icon>
  <description>Myriad Publishing</description>
  <frameHeight>600</frameHeight>
   <frameHeight>600</frameHeight>
  <mobileReady>true</mobileReady>
  <motif>Custom53: Bell</motif>
 <url>http://www.myriadpubs.com</url>
 <urlEncodingKey>UTF-8</urlEncodingKey>
</CustomTab>
```

Comment: If that solved please mark as answered !